# What is the motivation to continuous functions and measurable functions?

Tags: general-topology, measure-theory, motivation

In topology the objects of interest are the space open sets, and a function will be continuous if the inverse image of any open set is an open set. 
In measure theory the objects of interest are the measurable sets, and a function will be measurable if the inverse image of any measurable set is a measurable set.

What is the motivation and importance of the "inverse image" operation, and how this idea has been generalized?

Comment: Let $X, Y$ be metric spaces. Theorem: a function $f: X \to Y$ is continuous in the topological sense iff it's continuous in the metric space ($\varepsilon$-$\delta$) sense. The motivation, then, is to abstract away from the necessity of a metric while retaining the same ideas.

Comment: @MikeMiller: But how do we know the two "categories" are similar-enough in some sense so that the properties of one can be abstracted to the other?

Comment: The continuity is equivalent to $x ∈ \overline{A} \implies f(x) ∈ \overline{f[A]}$, i.e. if a point is arbitrarily close to a set, then its image is arbitrarily close to the image of the set. This sounds like continuity.

Comment: @user87690: This is my favorite characterization (or definition) of continuity. Do you know if there is such a thing for measurable maps?

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg: I don't know about such a thing for measurable maps. Since measurable sets are not stable under arbitrary unions or intersections, one cannot define an analogue of the closure operation. On the other hand, measurable sets are closed under complements. One can just say that measurability of a map means that the map induces a $σ$-complete homomorphism of $σ$-complete Boolean algebras.

Comment: @MikeMiller: I am trying to understand something more general, that formalize the idea of having the inverse image preserve the structure of object of interest between spaces. Continuity (with open sets) and measurability (with measurable sets) are specific examples, but understanding the general framework should provide some information on why things were defined that way, and why it works.

Comment: I think this might be more a case of convergent evolution than an underlying shared structure. I mean to say, its easier from a teaching perspective to merge the presentation of the theories than keep their differences more clearly in view. Fundamentally, continuity and topology arose to usefully extend the idea of closeness that metric spaces have. Measure theory arose to perfect the Riemann integral. That we've slowly melded their pedagogy over the centuries might not mean anything deep.

Comment: I absolutely agree with user24142 here. On the other hand, I have learnt that in mathematics there are no really coincidences. Almost every two mathematical notions or constructions, which look similar, turn out to be actually instances of one single general concept. Therefore, I think that this question is quite interesting.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. First, a few words about inverse images. If $X$ is a set, then the powerset $\mathcal{P} X$ is a poset. If $f: X \to Y$ is a function, then the inverse image function $\mathcal{P}Y \to \mathcal{P}X$ is order-preserving, and it has *both* left and right adjoints -- which in particular means it preserves both meets and joins. The left adjoint is the forward-image function but *it* doesn't have its own left adjoint, and correspondingly it doesn't preserve joins. So inverse image has better properties than forward image.

   Also, even if you don't consider the poset structure on $\mathcal{P}X$, it's still the homset $[X,2]$, and inverse image is just the precomposition function $[Y,2] \overset{[f,\mathrm{id}]}{\to} [X,2]$. The forward image doesn't admit such a simple description.
2. Next, let me just write down the obvious analogy between topological spaces and measure spaces, in a not-particularly-elegant way.

   A topological space is a set equipped with a geometric sublattice (i.e. closed under finite meets and arbitrary joins) of its powerset; a continuous map is a function between carrier sets whose inverse image preserves the sublattice. A measurable space is a set equipped with a boolean sigma-sublattice (i.e. closed under countable meets and joins, and under complements); a measurable map is a function between carrier sets whose inverse image preserves the sublattice.
3. So in each case we have a functor, in both cases called $\mathcal{P}: \mathsf{Set} \to \mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}$ (where $\mathcal C$ is respectively the category $\mathsf{GeomLat}$ of geometric lattices and $\sigma \mathsf{Bool}$ of Boolean $\sigma$-lattices), and the category we're interested in is the full subcategory of the comma category $(\mathcal{C}^\mathrm{op}\downarrow \mathcal{P})$ whose objects are monomorphisms in $\mathcal{C}$.

   In both cases, $\mathcal{P}$ factors through $\mathcal{P}: \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{CompLat}^\mathrm{op}$ (here $\mathsf{CompLat}$ is complete lattices and meet-and-join-preserving maps), via obvious forgetful functors $\mathsf{CompLat} \to \mathcal{C}$. Also, I'm not sure how relevant this is, but in both cases $\mathcal{C}$ is monadic over $\mathsf{Set}$ (although the monadic functor doesn't appear in this picture).
4. I believe both forgetful functors $\mathsf{Top} \to \mathsf{Set}$, $\mathsf{Meas} \to \mathsf{Set}$ are [topological functors](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/topological+concrete+category). This has to do with the fact that the lattice of all topologies (resp. the lattice of all measurable structures) on a set $X$ is itself a complete lattice.

   There is a structure theory for topological categories over $\mathsf{Set}$ which you can read about in [The Joy of Cats](http://katmat.math.uni-bremen.de/acc/acc.pdf#page=384). I'm a little confused about how it applies to $\mathsf{Top}$ and $\mathsf{Meas}$, though.
5. There's an interesting way to construct $\mathsf{Top}$ 2-categorically: just as the algebras of the ultrafilter monad are compact Hausdorff spaces, so the *lax* algebras of the ultrafilter monad (in a suitable 2-categorical sense) are exactly topological spaces. See [here](http://www.math.yorku.ca/~tholen/ProMat_V_.pdf) for details. I'm not aware of an analogous construction of $\mathsf{Meas}$; this is related to the discussion in the comments about the lack of a "convergence"-like relation for measurable spaces.
6. $[-,2]: \mathsf{Set}^\mathrm{op} \to \mathsf{Set}$ is right adjoint to itself, and is in fact monadic (this is irrelevant, I just can't help myself mentioning it). But for what it's worth, consider the underlying functor $T = [[-,2],2]: \mathsf{Set} \to \mathsf{Set}$ of the induced monad. A topology or a measure on a set $X$ is just a map $1 \to TX$ satisfying some properties. $\mathsf{Top}$ and $\mathsf{Meas}$ are kind of like full subcategories of the slice category $(1 \downarrow T)$, except that would require every open (resp. measurable) set to be a preimage of an open (resp. measurable) set in order for a map to be "continuous" (resp. "measurable"); if we could just take an appropriate sort of lax slice category we'd have what we want. But I'm not sure about the details.
7. For lots of purposes, you can forget about the points of a topological space and just work with the open sets. This is called [locale theory](http://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/locale). I presume people do similar things with $\sigma$-lattices. This removes a lot of the awkwardness of these analogous descriptions, and just leaves us with (the opposites of) two natural subcategories of the category of lattices.